# Can I Hurt my Ubuntu System by installing LXDE

Tags: 12.04, installation, unity, hp, lxde

I Have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and recently installed LXDE. I had heard that it could damage the Unity... but there was no confermation of the bug i havent had issues yet but was wrorried that they could arise...

Tech info:
OS:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
, Memory: 993.1 Mib
Processer intel (r) CPU T2050 (Dual Core) @ 1.6 GHZ (1600Mhz), Os:32 bit.... im using an HP Pavillion DV5220us

I have a clean install (was done within a day of this post)

I am not dual booting

I installed LXDE via USC

Package installed : LXDE (the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment)

Add ons:

Archiver for .arj

Galculator

Minmalist music player for LXDE (lxmusic)

Freedesktop.org menue compliant window manager scripts

Package manager for rpm

Command Line screen capture utility

Automatic screensaver for X

package version : lxde 0.5.0-4ubuntu3

License: Open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add or update a package, it's possible that the package or its dependences will have bugs that can affect how the rest of your system preforms.  The most common way this happens is that currently working customized configuration files are over written by the default version upon installation of an updated package (the bug I mention below is a result of this).

However, especially when a user is trying to install a package that is no longer maintained, or one that hasn't yet been accepted to the general repository, it's not all that uncommon to come across dependency related issues.

The most simple form of this is a versioning issue that is caused when the package you want to install has a co-dependancies with other packages on your system that can only be satisfied by installing an downstream or upstream version of a file on your system.

While usually not a problem, package-maintainers often claim that their package has indefinite forward compatibly with packages they are dependant on.  However if the maintainer of the package depended on makes an unexpected change upstream, this can break your system (and indeed has caused me problems when adding new desktop environments to saucy)

In other cases, the dependences required by the package you are installing conflict with what's already installed on your system.  When this happens the package manager may ask you to remove some packages that you may be relying on in order to install and satisfy the dependencies of the new packages.   This can be avoided by carefully reviewing the purpose any packages that are requested for removal.

In some rare cases where packages on your system did not adequately declare all of their dependencies, you may find some packages no longer work even though they claim to have all their dependencies satisfied.

If you always use either synaptic, or aptitude to do your package installs, then you'll have a better chance of recovering form this situation.  Unlike apt-get, synaptic, and aptitude keep a log of **exactly** what was installed and removed, and thus allow you to easily revert to your previous state.

---

I have personally experienced a problem with trying to co-install Unity and another lightweight desktop environment, so I wouldn't be surprised to hear that LXDE also doesn't work well with unity installed.  That said, the likely hood is low and recovery via aptitude (or synaptic provide you can still access the GUI) is easy.

Nevertheless, I found the fight to keep unity happy with openbox and enlightenment really wasn't worth it to me, especially considering the extremely slow performance of Unity's dash.

After trying a plethora of other environments and distros, I settled on KDE via Kubuntu and/or LinuxMint as a better choice to replace Unity as a full fledged desktop because it still provides access to ubuntu support channels, and overall seemes to be better suited for traditional desktop use.  I do, however, still run Unity on my lower powered netbooks/nettops/tablets where I'm less likely to use dash anyway.

Comment: When the concern is specifically about dependencies, you can run `sudo apt-get update` and then `apt-get -s install <package>`. This *simulates* an installation (because of the `-s` flag). The absence of `sudo` in the second command is intentional. Like attempting to install the package, that reveals any dependencies first. Unlike attempting to install it, there's essentially no risk of accidentally going ahead and installing the package even if you don't like what other changes would be made. And the output of `apt-get -s ...` can be posted to Ask Ubuntu for advice on its significance.

Comment: Indeed, but dependencies change with updates, and thus one can never be sure that different desktop interfaces won't conflict.

Comment: They shouldn't change. That would typically be considered a serious bug and ought to be very rare. If you're know of a specific situation where this has happened and broke something for anyone (in a still-supported release), I highly recommend filing a bug. [Within a single, stable Ubuntu release, only updates to for security bugs and serious stability problems are provided.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) Updates introducing new features, which are the sort one would expect to alter dependencies--as well as any updates bringing major changes--are deferred to future releases.

Comment: @EliahKagan I checked and there was bug was already filed and confirmed, which seems to be the OPs concern.

Comment: here's one of the many bugs that you might find by installing an alternate desktop environment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1059235

Comment: I'm only talking about dependency-related problems (as per the beginning of my first comment). That appears to have been a beta-only bug not related to dependencies. I've run LXDE and Unity side by side on several Ubuntu systems without problems, but I do *not* maintain that the author of this question won't have problems; I would have answered this if I thought that. Rather, everything I've commented here is *specifically* about dependency issues, how to anticipate them, and how they are typically kept under control by Ubuntu's patching policy.

Comment: @EliahKagan sorry for not being more clear, that is one of many bugs I encounted while trying to run enlightenment or openbox; I cannot seem to find my dependancy issue were nautils was broken by an upstream package.  That said, I think I'm finally understanding concern, as it's less likely that it's an actual dependency than a broken configuration file in an upstream package.

Comment: I will keep this updated if i face any new issues... i have noticed that LXDE works fine still the GNOME and OPENBOX options dont if i go to the OPENBOX/GENOME option i can force log out using a suto command but if i choose the OPENBOX option in the list it just shows a gray screen and im not able to do much with it except hard shutdow with physical buttons... i will keep posted and post any issues i come accross. hopefully maybe the issues that were spoken of were maybe taken care of when i updated the kernel. thank you all.

Comment: @stens97 that is because openbox is just a window manager, you need to set start up scripts to launch things like a task bar, background and widgets. If you right click on the desktop the applications menu should be there, but needs to have certain apps installed to keep it up to date.